# jgrapht - get list of all traversed nodes

Tags: java, graph, jgrapht

Here is the sample code for finding the shortest path with Dijkstra algorithm:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    SimpleDirectedWeightedGraph<String, DefaultWeightedEdge> graph = new SimpleDirectedWeightedGraph<String, DefaultWeightedEdge>(DefaultWeightedEdge.class);
    graph.addVertex("vertex1");
    graph.addVertex("vertex2");
    graph.addVertex("vertex3");
    graph.addVertex("vertex4");
    graph.addVertex("vertex5");

    DefaultWeightedEdge e1 = graph.addEdge("vertex1", "vertex2");
    graph.setEdgeWeight(e1, 5);

    DefaultWeightedEdge e2 = graph.addEdge("vertex2", "vertex3");
    graph.setEdgeWeight(e2, 3);

    DefaultWeightedEdge e3 = graph.addEdge("vertex4", "vertex5");
    graph.setEdgeWeight(e3, 6);

    DefaultWeightedEdge e4 = graph.addEdge("vertex2", "vertex4");
    graph.setEdgeWeight(e4, 2);

    DefaultWeightedEdge e5 = graph.addEdge("vertex5", "vertex4");
    graph.setEdgeWeight(e5, 4);

    DefaultWeightedEdge e6 = graph.addEdge("vertex2", "vertex5");
    graph.setEdgeWeight(e6, 9);

    DefaultWeightedEdge e7 = graph.addEdge("vertex4", "vertex1");
    graph.setEdgeWeight(e7, 7);

    DefaultWeightedEdge e8 = graph.addEdge("vertex3", "vertex2");
    graph.setEdgeWeight(e8, 2);

    DefaultWeightedEdge e9 = graph.addEdge("vertex1", "vertex3");
    graph.setEdgeWeight(e9, 10);

    DefaultWeightedEdge e10 = graph.addEdge("vertex3", "vertex5");
    graph.setEdgeWeight(e10, 1);

    System.out.println("Shortest path from vertex1 to vertex5:");
    List<DefaultWeightedEdge> shortest_path = DijkstraShortestPath.findPathBetween(graph,"vertex1", "vertex5");
    System.out.println(shortest_path);
}
```

Is there a possibility to get a list of nodes that have been reached and marked as visited by the algorithm? I've seen that there is something called [TraversalListener](http://jgrapht.org/javadoc/org/jgrapht/event/TraversalListener.html), but it looks like applies only to iterators, like BreadthFirstIterator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like there is no facility for this using `DijkstraShortestPath` class. This is because traversal listener are added to graph iterator and the iterator used by `DijkstraShortestPath` can't be accessed.

As such, the only solution would be to copy `DijkstraShortestPath` code into a new class (let's call it `MyDijkstraShortestPath`) and add the traversal listener.

First, you need to create a class `MyTraversalListener` that inherits from `TraversalListenerAdapter`, and override the method you want.

```
class MyTraversalListener<V, E> extends TraversalListenerAdapter<V, E> {
     // override the method you want, like vertexTraversed and edgeTraversed
}
```

Then, in the constructor of our new `MyDijkstraShortestPath` class, we need to add it:

```
ClosestFirstIterator<V, E> iter =
    new ClosestFirstIterator<V, E>(graph, startVertex, radius);
iter.addTraversalListener(new MyTraversalListener<V, E>());
```

Comment: That's what I was afraid of. Thanks anyways!